# Calculating a floor sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Is there any explicit closed form expression for $\sum_{k=1}^{\dfrac{p-1}2} \bigg\lfloor \dfrac{kq}p \bigg\rfloor-\bigg\lfloor \dfrac{k(q-1)}{(p-1)} \bigg\rfloor$ , where $p,q$ are odd primes ?

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}\left\lfloor\frac{kq}{p}\right\rfloor$$
gives the number of lattice points in the region given by $0<x<\frac{p}{2},0<y\leq\frac{q}{p}x$, hence the original sum gives the number of lattice points in the region given by $0<x<\frac{p}{2}$, $\frac{q-1}{p-1}x<y\leq\frac{q}{p}x$. For any $x$ in the range $0<x<\frac{p}{2}$, there is at most one $y$ such that the constraint $\frac{q-1}{p-1}x<y\leq\frac{q}{p}x$ is fulfilled, since $\left|\frac{q}{p}-\frac{q-1}{p-1}\right|x<1.$ In a certain sense, the original sum accounts for very good rational approximations of $\frac{q}{p}$ with a denominator smaller than $p/2$, hence the value of the original sum depends on the continued fraction of $\frac{q}{p}$. In particular, the value of the original sum is bounded by (half) the length of the continued fraction of $\frac{q}{p}$.